# What is the difference between the ‘cssRules’ and ‘rules’ objects?

Tags: javascript, css, document

What is the difference between:

```js
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
```

and

```js
document.styleSheets[0].rules
```

I noticed that the second is also supported by IE8 and previous. But what is the difference between these two objects?

Comment: I recommend used cssRules, look a web said difference http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml

Comment: There is no `rules` property on the standard [CSSStyleSheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet) interface. Internet Explorer 8 and previous versions used [the `rules` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531199(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of the proper `cssRules` property.

Comment: Just a small detail: The standard sems to have been dated in 13 November, 2000, `rules` collection was introduced in IE4 in 1997...

Answer (score 9):

The properties [`cssRules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules) and [`rules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/rules) are constructed through the same steps. Hence they result in the same object. `rules` is deprecated and it is provided only for the sake of compatibility with the existing sites.

To answer your question, there is no difference at all. The object `cssRules` is officially supported whereas `rules` is deprecated.

See the [CSSWG spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#legacy-css-style-sheet-members) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Rule is the object of StyleSheet object, which allows you to access and modify the individual rules of a stylesheet.

IE and Firefox vary in their implementation of the CSS Rule object, though luckily, the difference is mainly in the syntax:

> document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0] //access the first rule in Firefox
>   document.styleSheets[0].rules[0] //access the first rule in IE Win

As mentioned, IE and Firefox relies on two different CSS Rule objects to access a stylesheet's rules. Below lists the two objects:

[image]